# What is the name of this code construction: condition ? true_expression: false_expression

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

What is the correct term/name for the following construction:

```
string myString = (boolValue==true ? "true": "false");
```

Comment: When wikipedia comes back you can refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: which is a page dedicated to this operator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a ternary conditional expression.

Answer (score 10):

The C, C++, C# and Java standards all use the following terms:

- The operator is the *conditional operator*.
- Such an expression is a *conditional expression*.

So those are official names. Programmers often more loosely refer to it as *the* ternary operator since it is the only commonly used operator with 3 operands. Strictly speaking it is only *a* ternary operator.

Answer (score 6):

The `?:` operator is the "conditional operator".

`boolValue==true ? "true": "false"` is hence a conditional expression.

`myString = (boolValue==true ? "true": "false")` is a conditional expression that also has an assignment.

`string myString = (boolValue==true ? "true": "false");` is a statement that uses a conditional expression in a declaration and assignment.

`?:` is often referred to as "the ternary operator". Strictly it's only *a* ternary operator, but since it's the only one in those languages then referring to *the* ternary operator is valid though it's applying a label based on a fact separate to its own internal definition. Where we to add an operator to a language like `x § y ¶ z` which took all three of `x`, `y` and `z` as operands then it would also be a ternary operator and while the conditional operator would still be *a* ternary operator, it would no longer be *the* ternary operator.

Answer (score 5):

This is called the **ternary conditional operator**.  I don't know if expressions using it have a specific name, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: They do have a specific name according to all the standards, and the operator has a specific name too – the *conditional operator*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: On a sidenote: In the C++ and C community, _the ternary operator_ is a common spelling, as there is only one ternary operator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Oops, I accidentally ignored your answer, sorry. I've added another one as I can imagine that some programmers don't know the relation of unary, binary and ternary (or n-ary).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is common parlance in the C# community, but in C and C++ many people commonly call this *the ternary operator*. Why?

- There are unary operators which expect a single operand, like in `-x`.
- There are binary operators which expect two operands, like in `x+x`.
- There is just one ternary operator, which expects three operands, like in `x?y:z`.

The "correct" name is "the conditional operator", because the result depends on the condition (the left most operand).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called "ternary operator".

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional expression, but when you use the "?" is called the "Conditional Operator."

Comment: It is not a statement, but an expression!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it is a statement, though one that includes an expression.

Comment: I don't think so. In C and C++ statements and expressions are syntactically & semantically different (and indeed, an expression -like an assignment- is a simple instruction).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch They are indeed different. `myString = (boolValue==true ? "true": "false")` is an expression, `string myString = (boolValue==true ? "true": "false");` is a statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **conditional expression**.

For readability, put the complex condition in parenthesis:

```
string myString = (somecond)?"true":"false";
```

In your case, just test the `boolValue` with

```
string MyString = boolValue?"true":"false".
```

Comment: For readability, unless it is very trivial (and a lot are), put the condition and the two controlled expressions on separate lines, just as you would for an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "ternary" and as far as I remember, when I learned Java (11/12 years ago), you couldn't do it OR at least, teachers weren't teaching this at all
Maybe it is because sometimes the code is less readable...