# Weird C# declaration of a variable

Tags: c#, variables, declaration, conditional-operator

I'm making some software which communicates with serial communication to some electronics through the COM port on my PC. I have to communicate with the SimplicTI protocol which I haven't used before. I have found a library which enables me to do the communication but since I would like to evolve as a programmer I would like to understand every single statement of this library. In the source code of the library I stumbled upon the following variable declaration:

```
byte len = (data == null) ? (byte)0 : (byte)data.Length
```

What is going on here? I can't seem to grasp this statement.

By the way the variable "data" is a byte array.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx">Ternary operator</a>

Comment: `By the way the variable "data" is a byte.` or byte array?

Comment: It's a byte array. I have edited the post...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Equivalent to:

```
byte len;

if (data == null)
{
    len = (byte)0;
}
else
{
    len = (byte)data.length;
}
```

Comment: Yes, or 0 if the byte array is null.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of a ternary conditional expression.  Check out this SO post:

[What is the name of this code construction: condition ? true_expression: false_expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907498/what-is-the-name-of-this-code-construction-condition-true-expression-false-e/8907534#8907534)

Basically its a shorthand for an if/else statement.  If data is null, then len is 0, else len is the length of the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's using the ternary operator `?` in place of an `if` statement. It means "if data is null set `len` to 0, otherwise set it to `data.Length`. `data` is probably a byte array (`byte[]`), not `byte`, right?

Comment: Oh yeah. Sry. Data is a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "Ternary" opperator A ? B : C

if A is true it returns B otherwise it returns C so:

X = A ? B : C

means

```
if (A) {
   X = B
} else {
   X = C
}
```

Comment: Usually called the conditional operator, or ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte len = (data == null) ? (byte)0 : (byte)data.Length
```

Let's dissect this.

First, we know that we're declaring the variable length, and initializing it to a variable: `byte len =`
Next, we have our test.  I'll remove the parentheses, since they are unnecessary: `data == null`
Then, we have the value to be returned if the test is true: `(byte)0`
Last, we have the value to be returned if the test is false: `(byte)data.Length`

Let's convert it to pseudocode:
    byte len = if (data is null) 0, else data.Length

To be more verbose:

> If data is null, let len = 0
>   Otherwise, let len = Length of data

This is called "the" ternary operator.  Is is the only operator that takes three arguments: the test, the value-if-true, and the value-if-false.  Many languages have it, and its syntax does not vary much from language to language, if at all.

Technically, it is just syntax sugar (a shortcut, and bytecode-equivalent) for the following:
    byte len;
    if (data == null)
    {
         len = 0;
    }
    else
    {
         len = data.Length;
    }

It can be used outside of variable declarations.  For example, we could have the following:
    return data == null ? 0 : data.Length;

Some programmers consider use the ternary operator to be a poor programming practice due to readability issues.  Personally, I often find its alternative to be overly verbose and less readable.

It's worth noting that C# goes a step further and even has syntax sugar for its syntax sugar.  The following three snippets of code are all equivalent:

```
// Most verbose method:
object a;
if (b == null)
{
    a = c;
}
else
{
    a = b;
}

// Significantly less verbose:
object a = b == null ? c : b;

// Now this is just plain awesome:
object a = b ?? c;
```

That last operator means, "return b unless it is null, in which case, return c".  It's very useful--don't forget it!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write such a long and useful reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean data is `byte[]`. Anyways, it looks like they are assuming that the value of `data.Length` is no longer than a `byte` (0 to 255). So, they are trying to initialize the value `len`, which is the length of the byte buffer, accommodating the possibility that `data` might be null, in a single statement using a ternary operator.